# Does filtering by wavelet decomposition and reconstruction introduce a phase shift in the filtered signal?

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, wavelet, filtering, discrete-wavelet-transform

I am removing low frequency noise from a signal using Matlab using the DWT and then reconstruction at a specific level:

I am removing the approximation signal at level 10 which approximates the low frequency noise

```
signal sampled at 500 hz

[a,b] = wavedec(signal,13,'db8');    % DWT to max level
lfnoise = wrcoef('a',a,b,'db8',10);  % Take approximation at lvl 10 as estimate of low freq noise
final = signal - lfnoise;            % Substract noise to remove from signal
```

Does this introduce a phase shift in the final filtered signal?  Visually it does not seem to add a significant phase shift because the major and high frequency features of the signal remain aligned, but I want to be able to tell if this introduces a phase shift or if it is equivalent to a zero phase filter.

Thanks for the help!